# How to use a value for psql copy command parameter?

Tags: python, postgresql, cursor, psql

Using python and psql.

```
sql = '''
      SELECT * FROM test
      '''.format(self.schema)        

self.cur.execute(sql)

return self.cur.fetchall()

-----------------------------
export_data = self.get_data() // the return of fetchall

if export_data:
cmd = [
'psql',
"\COPY {0} to 'test/test_dump.csv' DELIMITER ',' NULL ''"
.format(export_data)
]
```

For example, after get a query result and fetchall it at a value.

How to I copy or export it as file with psql command?

```
COPY (SELECT * FROM my_table) TO :path CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;
```

I know how to get a data from copy parameter directly.
But I want to use the fetched value as parameter.

```
cmd = [
'psql',
"\COPY {0} to 'test/test_dump.csv' DELIMITER ',' NULL ''"
.format(export_data)
]
```

Above setting seems weird... how to I do it?

Comment: Why not use `psycopg2` built in [Copy support](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.